# sql server 2008 r2 cursor is not forwarded by fetch

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I stumbled upon a very strange behaviour while working on some T-SQL Code.

I am working on a SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 (build nr.: 10.50.4000).

My question to you guys is if anybody has seen such a behaviour before or if anybody might be able to explain it to me.

So,

#### What's the situation?

We have a table, which looks like that:

```
product_number  |  id_object | position_in_product
---------------------------------------------------
1               | 101        | 1
1               | 102        | 1
1               | 103        | 1
2               | 201        | 1
2               | 202        | 1
2               | 203        | 1
```

Multiple object ids are allocated to one product number. The order should be defined by the position_in_product column. The funny part lies exactly in establishing that order.
Of course, after doing that the table should look like this:

```
product_number  |  id_object | position_in_product
---------------------------------------------------
1               | 101        | 1
1               | 102        | 2
1               | 103        | 3
2               | 201        | 1
2               | 202        | 2
2               | 203        | 3
```

#### What's going on?

To update the order column we create a cursor with the following statement:

```
DECLARE
table_runner CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FOR 
  SELECT id_object, product_number
  FROM table
  WHERE ident = @ident
  ORDER BY product_number
```

By using this cursor and counting the rows with the same product_number we should be able to  update the position_in_product column. (This has worked in every installation until now)

To move the cursor to the next row we use this:

```
FETCH next from table_runner
INTO @table_runner$id_object, @table_runner$product_number
```

The whole function looks like this:

```
OPEN table_runner

FETCH next from table_runner
INTO @table_runner$id_object, @table_runner$product_number

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN                

   /* update_logic */              

   FETCH next from table_runner
   INTO @table_runner$id_object, @table_runner$product_number

END

CLOSE table_runner
```

And that is the part, that does not work as expected.
The fetch will not give me the next row. I am getting always the same result row.
The while loop does never end, the fetch_status is always 0, but the result stays the same.

#### The Workaround

After searching the web for quite a while without any results i decided to try a more pragmatical way and put another FETCH statement in.

I know that the id_object variable is unique and has to change in every loop cycle,
so i remembered the last fetched id and put this under the loop fetch statement:

```
if @id_object_memory = @table_runner$id_object 
begin

   FETCH next from table_runner
   INTO @table_runner$id_object, @table_runner$product_number
   set @id_object_memory = @table_runner$id_object 
end
else
   set @id_object_memory = @table_runner$id_object
```

With that the loop works as expected, the column in question is updated as it should and the cursor will reach the end of the result set.

#### The big ?

Has anyone any explanation for that?
There are more cursor defined in the same procedure and they all work as expected.
I have absolute no clue how to explain this.

So, thanks for reading ;)

Comment: You haven't shown the table definition including indexes or the update statement but probably some variant of the Halloween problem. You would need to specifically declare the cursor as static to avoid this. [Screenshot of relevant passage from Guru's guide to TSQL](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TUI6l.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help with the cursor issue, I've never seen this before, but should point out you don't need a cursor at all to do this update. You can simply use:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  Product_Number,
            ID_Object,
            Position_in_Product,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Product_Number 
                                            ORDER BY id_object)
    FROM    T
    WHERE   ident = @ident
)
UPDATE  CTE
SET     Position_in_Product = RowNumber;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd11f/2)**

You possibly don't even need to store this column, and can just use `ROW_NUMBER` in a query where the `position_in_product` is required.

Comment: My thoughts too. Who wants to debug some cursor issue when there is an obviously better way!

Comment: I will definitly try that! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Cursors are so 2000 `;-)`

Seriously though; avoid cursors at all costs. Set-based operations > looping.

Just create a view with the following:

```
CREATE VIEW your_view
  AS
SELECT product_number
     , id_object
     , Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY product_number ORDER BY id_object) As position_in_product
FROM   your_table
;
```

No need to ever perform the update; the row numbers will "automatically" recalculate.

Comment: I know this is not the preferred way to achive the desired result, the whole procedure is on the refactor list. That bit of code is about four years old. What confuses me is that it worked till three days ago.